# Referral tracking - not working when app is installed via desktop browser

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm tying to track referrals of my android application using google analytics and [url builder](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide#google-play-tracking).
It all works well, except for when I try to install from web page on the computer. If I go to the browser on desktop, open generated link and press install, app will not recieve referral parameters.

All the other methods work:
- If I send an INSTALL_REFERRER intent with adb shell, the app will recieve referral parameters as expected
- If I manually send Intent INSTALL_REFERRER from code, the app will recieve referral parameters as expected
- If I scan qrcode generated by [url builder](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide#google-play-tracking) with my device, the app will recieve referral parameters as expected

Does this mean that referral won't be passed when user installs app via web page from desktop?
If not, what makes this one case so special?

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Comment: I am facing the same problem if app installed via desktop can't get referer parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People noticed a change with later versions of the Market app, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19247). The thing is that the refferer gets passed the first time the app is started, not immediately after the installation.

But if that's not your issue, then maybe it's the known issue with old Android version, described [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#known-issues).
I found a [blog post](http://support.hasoffers.com/entries/22326108-google-play-web-versions-not-tracking-install-referrer) which explains how to overcome this with redirect links.